# How to make my python function go to a specific folder path and run a command line

Tags: python, command-line

I am trying to automate my build process. typically what I do is I go to a certain folder where my make scripts are at, open a CMD, type a command which is something like this "Bootstrap_make.bat /fic = Foo"

Now I want to do this from inside my python code. simple question is How to do this, i.e. how to; using python code. go to a certain path > and open a CMD >  and execute the command"

here is what I've tried

```
def myClick():
subprocess.run(["cd ..\Projects\ADAS\proj11\embedded_env\make_scripts" ])
subprocess.run(["bootstrap_make.bat","/fic= my_software_variant"])
```

However I git this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\aelkhate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1921, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)
> File "C:\E\ProductOne_Builder1.py", line 5, in myClick
> subprocess.run(["cd ..\Projects\ADAS\proj11\embedded_env\make_scripts" ])
> File "C:\Users\aelkhate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
> with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
> File "C:\Users\aelkhate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
> File "C:\Users\aelkhate\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
> hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: What have you tried so far? I would start with the documentation for the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: @larsks I updated my question, sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `os.system()`.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

This code is assuming you are on Windows because you are running a `.bat` file and trying to open a CMD window.

```py
import os

directory = './path/to/make/scripts'
buildCommand = './Bootstrap_make.bat'
buildArgs = '/fic = Foo'
# if you don't want a new cmd window you could do something like:
os.system('cd {} && {} {}'.format(directory, buildCommand, buildArgs))

# if you want a new cmd window you could do something like:
os.system('cd {} && start "" "{}" {}'.format(directory, buildCommand, buildArgs))
```

Comment: You sir are the best, just a note that os.system('cd {} && start "" "{}" '.format(directory, buildCommand)) resulted an error, however the first solution that uses the same command line works. thank you so much:) .

Comment: (it's mam or miss) I just realized my mistake. I forgot about arguments. Removing the second pair of quotes from around the {} should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), specifying the `cwd` (current working directory) kwarg.